# Pass props in Link react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react with react-router.
I am trying to pass property’s in a "Link" of react-router

```
var React  = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var CreateIdeaView = require('./components/createIdeaView.jsx');

var Link = Router.Link;
var Route = Router.Route;
var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;
var App = React.createClass({
  render : function(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Link to="ideas" params={{ testvalue: "hello" }}>Create Idea</Link>
        <RouteHandler/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var routes = (
  <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
    <Route name="ideas" handler={CreateIdeaView} />
    <DefaultRoute handler={Home} />
  </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function(Handler) {

  React.render(<Handler />, document.getElementById('main'))
});
```

The "Link" renders the page but does not pass the property to the new view.
Below is the view code

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');

var CreateIdeaView = React.createClass({
  render : function(){
    console.log('props form link',this.props,this)//props not recived
  return(
      <div>
        <h1>Create Post: </h1>
        <input type='text' ref='newIdeaTitle' placeholder='title'></input>
        <input type='text' ref='newIdeaBody' placeholder='body'></input>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = CreateIdeaView;
```

How can I pass data using "Link"?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

This line is missing `path`:

```
<Route name="ideas" handler={CreateIdeaView} />
```

Should be:

```
<Route name="ideas" path="/:testvalue" handler={CreateIdeaView} />
```

Given the following `Link` **(outdated v1)**:

```
<Link to="ideas" params={{ testvalue: "hello" }}>Create Idea</Link>
```

**Up to date as of v4/v5**:

```
const backUrl = '/some/other/value'
// this.props.testvalue === "hello"

// Using query
<Link to={{pathname: `/${this.props.testvalue}`, query: {backUrl}}} />

// Using search
<Link to={{pathname: `/${this.props.testvalue}`, search: `?backUrl=${backUrl}`} />
<Link to={`/${this.props.testvalue}?backUrl=${backUrl}`} />
```

<s>and in the `withRouter(CreateIdeaView)` components `render()`</s>, out dated usage of `withRouter` higher order component:

```
console.log(this.props.match.params.testvalue, this.props.location.query.backurl)
// output
hello /some/other/value
```

And in a functional components using the `useParams` and `useLocation` hooks:

```
const CreatedIdeaView = () => {
    const { testvalue } = useParams();
    const { query, search } = useLocation(); 
    console.log(testvalue, query.backUrl, new URLSearchParams(search).get('backUrl'))
    return <span>{testvalue} {backurl}</span>    
}
```

From the link that you posted on the docs, towards the bottom of the page:

> Given a route like `<Route name="user" path="/users/:userId"/>`

---

Updated code example with some stubbed query examples:

```js
// import React, {Component, Props, ReactDOM} from 'react';
// import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router'; etc etc
// this snippet has it all attached to window since its in browser
const {
  BrowserRouter,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  NavLink
} = ReactRouterDOM;

class World extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.dir(props);      
    this.state = {
      fromIdeas: props.match.params.WORLD || 'unknown'
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { match, location} = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h2>{this.state.fromIdeas}</h2>
        <span>thing: 
          {location.query 
            && location.query.thing}
        </span><br/>
        <span>another1: 
        {location.query 
          && location.query.another1 
          || 'none for 2 or 3'}
        </span>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class Ideas extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.dir(props);
    this.state = {
      fromAppItem: props.location.item,
      fromAppId: props.location.id,
      nextPage: 'world1',
      showWorld2: false
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
          <li>item: {this.state.fromAppItem.okay}</li>
          <li>id: {this.state.fromAppId}</li>
          <li>
            <Link 
              to={{
                pathname: `/hello/${this.state.nextPage}`, 
                query:{thing: 'asdf', another1: 'stuff'}
              }}>
              Home 1
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button 
              onClick={() => this.setState({
              nextPage: 'world2',
              showWorld2: true})}>
              switch  2
            </button>
          </li>
          {this.state.showWorld2 
           && 
           <li>
              <Link 
                to={{
                  pathname: `/hello/${this.state.nextPage}`, 
                  query:{thing: 'fdsa'}}} >
                Home 2
              </Link>
            </li> 
          }
        <NavLink to="/hello">Home 3</NavLink>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Link to={{
          pathname:'/ideas/:id', 
          id: 222, 
          item: {
              okay: 123
          }}}>Ideas</Link>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/ideas/:id/' component={Ideas}/>
          <Route path='/hello/:WORLD?/:thing?' component={World}/>
        </Switch>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('ideas'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/4.3.1/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/4.3.1/react-router.min.js"></script>

<div id="ideas"></div>
```

#updates:

See: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/0c6d51cd6639aff8a84b11d89e27887b3558ed8a/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#link-to-onenter-and-isactive-use-location-descriptors

> From the upgrade guide from 1.x to 2.x:
>
> `<Link to>`, onEnter, and isActive use location descriptors
>
> `<Link to>` can now take a location descriptor in addition to strings.
> The query and state props are deprecated.
>
> // v1.0.x
>
> ```
> <Link to="/foo" query={{ the: 'query' }}/>
> ```
>
> // v2.0.0
>
> ```
> <Link to={{ pathname: '/foo', query: { the: 'query' } }}/>
> ```
>
> // Still valid in 2.x
>
> ```
> <Link to="/foo"/>
> ```
>
> Likewise, redirecting from an onEnter hook now also uses a location
> descriptor.
>
> // v1.0.x
>
> ```
> (nextState, replaceState) => replaceState(null, '/foo')
> (nextState, replaceState) => replaceState(null, '/foo', { the: 'query' })
> ```
>
> // v2.0.0
>
> ```
> (nextState, replace) => replace('/foo')
> (nextState, replace) => replace({ pathname: '/foo', query: { the: 'query' } })
> ```
>
> For custom link-like components, the same applies for router.isActive,
> previously history.isActive.
>
> // v1.0.x
>
> ```
> history.isActive(pathname, query, indexOnly)
> ```
>
> // v2.0.0
>
> ```
> router.isActive({ pathname, query }, indexOnly)
> ```

#updates for v3 to v4:

- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/432dc9cf2344c772ab9f6379998aa7d74c1d43de/packages/react-router/docs/guides/migrating.md
- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/3803
- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/3669
- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/3430
- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/3443
- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/3803
- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/3636
- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/3397
- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/3288

The interface is basically still the same as v2, best to look at the CHANGES.md for react-router, as that is where the updates are.

*"legacy migration documentation" for posterity*

- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dc7facf205f9ee43cebea9fab710dce036d04f04/packages/react-router/docs/guides/migrating.md
- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/0c6d51cd6639aff8a84b11d89e27887b3558ed8a/upgrade-guides/v1.0.0.md
- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/0c6d51cd6639aff8a84b11d89e27887b3558ed8a/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md
- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/0c6d51cd6639aff8a84b11d89e27887b3558ed8a/upgrade-guides/v2.2.0.md
- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/0c6d51cd6639aff8a84b11d89e27887b3558ed8a/upgrade-guides/v2.4.0.md
- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/0c6d51cd6639aff8a84b11d89e27887b3558ed8a/upgrade-guides/v2.5.0.md

Comment: It seems that params is not supported in version 2.0, asumming test values is stored in the props, it would be something like <Link to={`/ideas/${this.props.testvalue}`}>{this.props.testvalue}</Link>

Comment: @Braulio thanks. I updated my answer and included some more of the docs for the differences for <Link> between v1 and v2

Comment: @Braulio: the correct way is: `<Link to={\`/ideas/${this.props.testvalue}\`}>{this.props.testvalue}</Link>`, with backticks

Comment: Yes, sorry, backticks got lost when I pasted the code going to fix it.

Comment: This works for me without using backticks `<Link to={'/ideas/'+this.props.testvalue }>{this.props.testvalue}</Link>`

Comment: The backticks-$ is the recommended way in ES6, compared to string concatenation using "+".

Comment: Is it still the same for react router v4?

Comment: @AnthonyKong reading through the change log, the interface is more or less still the same. They added some extras, for target, and error handling. I updated my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 166):

there is a way you can pass more than one parameter. You can pass "to" as object instead of string.

```
// your route setup
<Route path="/category/:catId" component={Category} / >

// your link creation
const newTo = { 
  pathname: "/category/595212758daa6810cbba4104", 
  param1: "Par1" 
};
// link to the "location"
// see (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location)
<Link to={newTo}> </Link>

// In your Category Component, you can access the data like this
this.props.match.params.catId // this is 595212758daa6810cbba4104 
this.props.location.param1 // this is Par1
```

Comment: exactly what I want.

Comment: This answer is very underrated. It isn't obvious but the documentation mentions this https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/to-object. It advises to pass data as a single object marked 'state'

Comment: This is the best answer to this question.

Comment: Been dealing with drama for way too long and this totally worked! V4

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: In the path attribute shouldnt  be "/category/595212758daa6810cbba4104" instead of mapping to article???

Comment: Worth noting that "pathname" cannot be a passed-in variable, only an in-line string. Don't know the reason but that's the only way <link to={object}/> works for me.

Comment: for me param1 isn't available in location.param1. Instead I wrapped param1 inside state attribute like { 
  pathname: "/category/595212758daa6810cbba4104", 
  state: {
           param1: "Par1" 
  }
}. Now param1 can be accessed as location.state.param1.(By the way I used functional component)

Comment: Hi, but is not posible to recover that param1 if i use new tab rigth? (target _blank...), or maybe if i recover part of the currenct query string?, can someone please help me :(.

Comment: This answer, while being great, won't work for V6 of `react-router-dom`. For that, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71064990/6772900).

Comment: If you are using a functional component, import the useLocation hook as follows `import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";`, get the location object `let location = useLocation();` and extract the parameter from `location.param1`

Answer (score 39):

I had the same problem to show an user detail from my application.

You can do this:

```
<Link to={'/ideas/'+this.props.testvalue }>Create Idea</Link>
```

or

```
<Link to="ideas/hello">Create Idea</Link>
```

and

```
<Route name="ideas/:value" handler={CreateIdeaView} />
```

to get this via `this.props.match.params.value` at your CreateIdeaView class.

You can see this video that helped me a lot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBxMljq9GSE

Comment: Precisely what the documentation says.  However, I have a case where DESPITE defining the Route as above, and configuring the LINK to pass the parameter value, the React component class does not have ANY this.props.params values picked up from the URL.  Any idea why this might happen?  It is like route binding is simply missing.  The render() in component class DOES engage, but there is no data passed into the component.

Comment: But then in your last example, how do you then pull the 'value' variable in the CreateIdeaView component?

Answer (score 38):

[See this post for reference](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-link/)

The simple is that:

```
<Link to={{
     pathname: `your/location`,
     state: {send anything from here}
}}
```

Now you want to access it:

```
this.props.location.state
```

Comment: does this work for class component,for me its not working

Comment: @lokesh yes, you need to wrap it in functional component and pass as `props`

Answer (score 23):

as for react-router-dom 4.x.x (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) you can pass params to the component to route to via:

```
<Route path="/ideas/:value" component ={CreateIdeaView} />
```

linking via (considering testValue prop is passed to the corresponding component (e.g. the above App component) rendering the link)

```
<Link to={`/ideas/${ this.props.testValue }`}>Create Idea</Link>
```

passing props to your component constructor the value param will be available via

```
props.match.params.value
```

Comment: Yes it works great <Link to={`/movie/detail/${this.state.id}`} className="btn btn-secondary btn-lg active">Detail</Link>

Answer (score 23):

Inside your Link component do the state

```
<Link to='register' state={{name:'zayne'}}>
```

Now to access the item in the page you went to, import useLocation

```
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';

const Register=()=>{

const location = useLocation()

//store the state in a variable if you want 
//location.state then the property or object you want

const Name = location.state.name

return(
  <div>
    hello my name is {Name}
  </div>
)

}
```

Comment: I exactly don't know how to say thanks to you!! 

Comment: The fact that it worked is all the thank you i need!

Answer (score 15):

After install `react-router-dom`

```
<Link
    to={{
      pathname: "/product-detail",
      productdetailProps: {
       productdetail: "I M passed From Props"
      }
   }}>
    Click To Pass Props
</Link>
```

and other end where the route is redirected do this

```
componentDidMount() {
            console.log("product props is", this.props.location.productdetailProps);
          }
```

Comment: am using the same way V5 . But in class component .But not working

Answer (score 11):

### Typescript

For approach mentioned like this in many answers,

```
<Link
    to={{
        pathname: "/my-path",
        myProps: {
            hello: "Hello World"
        }
    }}>
    Press Me
</Link>
```

I was getting error,

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'myProps' does not exist in type 'LocationDescriptorObject | ((location: Location) => LocationDescriptor)'

Then I checked in the [official documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/to-object) they have provided `state` for the same purpose.

So it worked like this,

```
<Link
    to={{
        pathname: "/my-path",
        state: {
            hello: "Hello World"
        }
    }}>
    Press Me
</Link>
```

And in your next component you can get this value as following,

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("received "+this.props.location.state.hello);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

To work off the answer above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44860918/2011818), you can also send the objects inline the "To" inside the Link object.

```
<Route path="/foo/:fooId" component={foo} / >

<Link to={{pathname:/foo/newb, sampleParam: "Hello", sampleParam2: "World!" }}> CLICK HERE </Link>

this.props.match.params.fooId //newb
this.props.location.sampleParam //"Hello"
this.props.location.sampleParam2 //"World!"
```

Answer (score 8):

**For v6:** *Attention! `state` should be outside from `to={}`*

```
// route setup
<Route path="/employee-edit/:empId" element={<EmployeeEdit />} / >
```

`Link` to Component

```
<Link to={"/employee-edit/1"} state={{ data: employee }} > Edit </Link>
```

or

```
<Link to={{
       pathname: "/employee-edit/1",
       search: "?sort=name",
       hash: "#the-hash",
     }}
       state={{ data: employee }} > Edit </Link>
```

**Note:** `state` is outside from `to{}`, but for
[v5](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object):

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/courses",
    search: "?sort=name",
    hash: "#the-hash",
    state: { fromDashboard: true }
  }}
/>
```

**Funtional component:**

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const LinkTest = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log("Location", location);
  return <h1>Link Test</h1>;
};

export default LinkTest;
```

**Class Component:** in order to work with hooks, we need to wrap it in functional component and pass props:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useLocation, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

class LinkTestComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return <h1>Link Test</h1>;
  }
}

export default () => (
  <LinkTestComponent params={useParams()} location={useLocation()} />
);
```

**Tested with:** `"react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",`

Answer (score 7):

**For v5**

```
 <Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/courses",
    search: "?sort=name",
    hash: "#the-hash",
    state: { fromDashboard: true }
  }}
/>
```

[React Router Official Site](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link)

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had a function component with empty props and this solved it:

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/dashboard/${device.device_id}`,
    state: { device },
  }}
>
  View Dashboard
</Link>
```

In your function component you should have something like this:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router"
export default function Dashboard() {
  const location = useLocation()
  console.log(location.state)
  return <h1>{`Hello, I'm device ${location.state.device.device_id}!`}</h1>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach would be to make use of the `to:object` within `link` as mentioned in documentation:
https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/courses",
    search: "?sort=name",
    hash: "#the-hash",
    state: { fromDashboard: true, id: 1 }
  }}
/>
```

We can retrieve above params (state) as below:

```
this.props.location.state // { fromDashboard: true ,id: 1 }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are just looking to replace the slugs in your routes, you can use `generatePath` that [was introduced in react-router 4.3 (2018)](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/releases/tag/v4.3.0). As of today, it isn't included in the [react-router-dom (web) documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web), but is in [react-router (core)](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/generatePath). [Issue#7679](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7679)

```
// myRoutes.js
export const ROUTES = {
  userDetails: "/user/:id",
}


// MyRouter.jsx
import ROUTES from './routes'

<Route path={ROUTES.userDetails} ... />


// MyComponent.jsx
import { generatePath } from 'react-router-dom'
import ROUTES from './routes'

<Link to={generatePath(ROUTES.userDetails, { id: 1 })}>ClickyClick</Link>
```

It's the same concept that `django.urls.reverse` has had for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this for a few hours and not a single answer in this topic worked for me. Finally I managed to find a solution for React Router 6 in the [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial).

Here is full example:

```
// App.js

<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/books/:bookId" element={ <BookDetails /> } />
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

```
// BookDetails.js

import React from "react"
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"

export default function BookPage() {
    const params = useParams()
    return <div> { console.log(params.bookId) } </div>
}
```

Note that `useParams` cannot be called inside a class component so you must use function component (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64816926/8086115) answer for details).

Answer (score 1):

In react-router **v6** it is with **state** and **useLocation**:

```
<Link to={`/foo`} state={{title: 'foo'}}>
```

```
import {useLocation} from "react-router-dom";

const FooPage = () => {
    const location = useLocation()

    return <>
        <h1>{location.state.title}</h1>
    </>
}
export default FooPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Route:

```
<Route state={this.state} exact path="/customers/:id" render={(props) => <PageCustomer {...props} state={this.state} />} />
```

And then can access params in your PageCustomer component like this: `this.props.match.params.id`.

For example an api call in PageCustomer component:

```
axios({
   method: 'get',
   url: '/api/customers/' + this.props.match.params.id,
   data: {},
   headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating 25-11-21
Thanks for alex-adestech.mx  who wrote above.
I was able to transfer the whole object and pull out all the necessary fields from it
in send-component :

```
<Button type="submit" component={NavLink} to={{
        pathname: '/basequestion',
        state: {question} }}
        variant="contained"
        size="small">Take test</Button>
```

in receive-component:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router"
const BaseQuestion = () => {
const location = useLocation();
const {description, title, images} = (location.state.question);
```

Answer (score 0):

for V5 (how to pass dynamic variable):

Component, which invokes:

```
const elementQuery = "/myElements/" + myElement.id + "/properties"

<Link to={{pathname: elementQuery}}>Properties</Link>
```

Router:

```
<Switch>
     <Route path="/myElements/:elementId/properties" component={PropertiesPage}/>
</Switch>
```

How to read dynamic parameter (:elementId) in the target (PropertiesPage) page:
property can be read in componentsDidMount() function:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // Getting id from react router path
    const elementId = this.props.match.params.elementId;
    /*
    * do something with elementId 
    */
}
```