# React use component with props in a different file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm currently creating a timer application in react. I have a dashboard where the user can control the timer and now I want a different window where only the component rendering the time is being displayed so it can captured by recording programs.
I've tried the following:

In my app.js

```
function MasterStopwatch(props) {
    return <span>{props.time}</span>
}
export { App, MasterStopwatch };
```

I'm passing in the props.time in the app.js

In my index.js

```
import { App, MasterStopwatch } from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    <Route path="/master" component={MasterStopwatch} />
  </Router>
  , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But when I visit the master route it displays nothing and doesn't show an error in the console.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi. Your _MasterStopwatch_ component requires *props.time*. Therefore, you have to pass it down. Try to update the fragment of code to:
`<Route path="/master" time="<yourValue>" component={MasterStopwatch} />`

Comment: I'm passing in props.time in app.js. Isn't that working?

Comment: In this case it won't work 'cause every component deals with those props what they get primary as parameters. Like <myComponent propOne="1">

Comment: is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Yes. Use [<Link />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115324/pass-props-in-link-react-router) to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per your route MasterStopwatch should be child component of App.

if you are passing props to MasterStopwatch you need to pass it from parentComponent App.

```
    export default class App extends React.component {
        ....
        ....
        render(){

           return(
           <div>
              <MasterStopwatch  {...props}/>
           </div>
          )
        }
     }

    export function MasterStopwatch(props) {
        return <span>{props.time}</span>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your App and MasterStopWatch as follows:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
render() {
   return React.cloneElement(
        this.props.children, 
        {time: this.props.time}
    );
}
```

}

```
export default class MasterStopWatch extends React.Component {
render() {
   return <span>{this.props.time}</span>
}
```

}

Source: http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2015/11/02/pass-props-to-handler-component-in-react-router/