# ReactJS- Use slug instead of Id in the URL with React router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

**In short:** I want to show the slug instead of the Id in the URL, whats the best way to do that?

In my app.js component I am using React-router this way so far:

```
 <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Main}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home}></IndexRoute>
        <Route path="/profile/:slug" component={Split}></Route>
    </Route>

  </Router>
```

Then in my profile component I am using Link to go to that specific profile via the slug:

```
<Link to={'/profile/' + username.slug}>{username}</Link>
```

I was thinking of keying them together in my profile reducer or something?

Any tips would be very helpful!

Comment: Why do you have to bind the id with the slug? What does that even mean? And why do you have a `<Link />` component linking to itself?

Comment: Your question isn't about Redux - if you want answers about react-router I would recommend adding the correct tags and removing those that are irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Sorry if it was misleading, I have edited so it should be better. But how do you normally do this in react, showing the slug or the username in Url instead of the id? :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass props in Link react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115324/pass-props-in-link-react-router)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just do it with the way you have set up your route and then as you're using redux (because you said you were before edits) I would use `mapStateToProps` to filter or however it is you are passing the details as props.

for **example**:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  user: state.users.items.filter(user => user.slug === ownProps.params.slug),
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The best way I have found to do this is to have two objects within your state, one is users keyed by user id, the other is a slug-id lookup, keyed by slug.  Say your users look like this:

```
{
    _id: 1234
    username: 'Mary Poppins',
    slug: 'mary-poppins',
    likes: [ 'umbrellas' ]
}
```

Then your state would look like:

```
{
    users: {
        1234: {
            username: 'Mary Poppins',
            slug: 'mary-poppins',
            likes: ['umbrellas']
        }
    },
    slugs: {
        'mary-poppins': 1234
    }
}
```

Now when you are rendering `Link` components, you use:

```
<Link to=`/profile/${user.slug}`>{user.username}</Link>
```

And to select the user when you have the slug, you would have a selector such as:

```
const user = ( slug ) => ( state ) => state.users[state.slugs[slug]];
```

Comment: I understand the logic to this. If it's unsafe to show the user id in the route url - is this a standard way to overcome that or is there a newer convention?

Answer (score 0):

```
**//Server Side Communicate with frontend. Product data....**
const products = [
  {
    img:"https://cdn-images-fishry.azureedge.net/product/Krunch-500x360-a6056d0-kfc.png/xs",
    title:"Kuranch burger",
    discription:"Enjoy the crispy chicken fillet in a soft bun with spicy mayo and our signature sauce with fresh lettuce.",
    price:210,
    slug:"EVERYDAY-VALUE",
  },
  {
    img:"https://cdn-images-fishry.azureedge.net/product/Krunch-500x360-a6056d0-kfc.png/xs",
    title:"Kurnach burger",
    discription:"Enjoy the crispy chicken fillet in a soft bun with spicy mayo and our signature sauce with fresh lettuce.",
    price:200,
    slug:"EVERYDAY-VALUE",
  },


  ]
```

//then

```
app.get("/products/:slug", function (req, resp) {
  const slugs = req.params.slug;
  const pro = products.filter(p=>p.slug==slugs) 
  resp.send(pro);
});
```