# how to pass parameters to component using react route link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react and am trying to link to another page using the  tag. For example, I want to link back to the login screen with a parameter signupCompleted like so:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/', query: { signupCompleted: true } }}>
    <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick="sendSignupRequest" className="pull-
     right confirm-button-style">Send</Button>
</Link>
```

My component is routed to a path in my app.js:

```
<Route exact path='/' component={LoginPage} />
```

and in loginPage.js I try to reach the passed parameter in the constructor:

```
this.state = {
      signupCompleted: props.signupCompleted,
    };
```

However that is never set to true. I've looked at [Pass props in Link react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115324/pass-props-in-link-react-router), but nothing seems to do the trick.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `query: { signupCompleted: true }` doing ? is it a  string represenation of query parameters or query to persist to the location ? which version of `react-router-dom` are you using

Comment: @Aaqib It's suppose to be used to indicate to the loginpage if it has been redirected from pressing the sign up button where the <Link> tag is, its suppose to be a boolean. I'm running version 4.2.2 of react-router-dom

Answer (score 1):

As stated [Here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md) you can pass object as :

`pathname:` A string representing the path to link to.

`search:` A string represenation of query parameters.

`hash:` A hash to put in the URL, e.g. #a-hash.

`state:` State to persist to the location.

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: '/courses',
  search: '?sort=name',
  hash: '#the-hash',
  state: { signupCompleted: true }
}}/>
```

above is copied from [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md)

Now inside your `Login.js`

You can do it initially set `signupCompleted` to `false` :

```
this.state = { signupCompleted: false };
```

Comment: thank you @Aaqib for your answer! I have changed the link to be <Link to={{pathname: '/', state: { signupCompleted: true }}}> and in my login.js i have this.state = { signupCompleted: false}; however it still doesn't seem to ever set the variable to true.

Comment: Can you show your component where you are using Link ?

Comment: I just have a signupPage.js where in the render() method I have a Link tag with a bootstrap button like so:

<Link to={{ pathname: '/', state: { signupCompleted: true }}}>
                 <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick="sendSignupRequest" className="pull-right confirm-button-style">Send</Button></Link>

The routes are both declared in the main App.js component:

render() { return (
<Router>
     <Route exact path='/' component={LoginPage} />
     <Route exact path='/Signup' component={SignupPage}/>
</Router>
    );
}

Comment: And where have you declared `this.state = {{ signupCompleted: false }`

Comment: In the constructor of the loginpage:  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      signupCompleted: false,
    };
  }

Answer (score 0):

Define the route as following:

```
<Route path="/login/:signupCompleted" component={LoginPage} />
```

The Link should be:

```
<Link to={`/login/${signupCompleted}`}>Login</Link>
```

And in the LoginPage component, `this.props.match.params.id` is the value of signupCompleted.