# ReactJs Pass data between multiple components using Id field

Tags: javascript

How can i pass Data from Main Component to child component based on the record Id. I have a `index.js` and  `detail.js` pages. In the index page i have a link as  `<Link to={{ pathname:`/cards/**${results.id}**`, state: results }} className={`card-wrapper restore-${results.id}`}> {results.first_name} </Link>` when i click on the link i want to send the data associated to that record /Id value of the link to the detail page and display.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115324/pass-props-in-link-react-router ?

Comment: No @Vivek My only problem is replace `{cardData.data.Table[0].first_name}` by id of current record something like `{cardData.data.Table[i].first_name}` or `{cardData.data.Table[id].first_name}`

Comment: using props send data to children is very complex so i would prefer to use redux here

Comment: @kiran i am newbie to both react and redux any similar example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've examined your code and you need to do 2 changes:
From your index.js file, you need to change your link's to prop to:

```js
to={{ pathname: `/cards/${results.id}`, state: results }}
```

In your details.js, change your render function to:

```js
render() {
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    const data = cardData.data.Table.find(item => item.id === id)
    return (
      // Card details compoment
      <div className="card-details">
        <h2>{data.first_name}</h2>
        <h2>{data.id}</h2>

        <Link
          to={{
            pathname: "/",
            state: this.props.location.state
          }}
        >
          <button>Return to list</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Notice in the Link that you are linking to `/cards/${results.id}`, the id is the id of the record from the database.

Then in details.js,you find from the data a record with the id from the params and you use the data in that record.

You had done 2 mistakes:

1. You were linking to `/cards/${results.index}` in index.js, `results.index` is undefined.
2. In details.js, you were referencing data for example as:

```js
cardData.data.Table[id].first_name
```

But `cardData.data.Table` is an array of Objects and the ids are properties of the objects. cardData.data.Table[id] would only return data for an id such as 1002 if that array had at least 1003 objects in it.

Comment: Working Perfect! you the best !!!! you save my life!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: in my local i have id =1001 in sand box id="1001" how can i update the code?   i am getting Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined but i checked it all works Perfect!!!!. when i change id from 1001 to "1001" it works. your answer/solution is perfect need your help updating the code

Comment: Am not sure where the difference in values is originating from with info you are providing but you can convert between strings and numbers using String and Number functions. Pass a string to Number and you get an integer - String(1001) should return "1001", Number("1001") should return 1001. I don't know if this helps.

Comment: yep i changed to `    const data = cardData.data.Table.find(item => Number(item.id) === Number(id));` and all work Perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can pass cardData.data.Table data to  as props & get id from router like   .....params.id.

Then replace cardData.data.Table[0] by cardData.data.Table[i].

Comment: Thank you for the reply, can you please make it clear? i am new to this react. i have my live code here https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-booth-o0488?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark