# How pass data selected item menu from main page to products page in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, menu, pass-data, react-context

On the main page, the top menu looks like this 1 image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3aLs.png). On the product page, the menu in the sidebar looks like this 2 image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRbR0.png). How can I pass from the main page to the product page that the item Men is selected, the category of Jackets and Trench Coats and the catalog of Leather jackets.

Comment: you could use context or pass it as props to the other component if possible

Comment: you could use redux, or other state management libs.

Comment: Can i use component Link from react-router or contextApi?

Comment: Can someone send link to open source projects (github, bitbacket or etc.)?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you should use url route / params - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44860918/863110