# How to access the state that was sent using Link to in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to send props to another component when the **Link to** is used.

```
const printArr = sameLetterArr.map((obj, idx) => {
  return (
    <Link to={{ pathname: '/coursePage', state: { linkState: 'hello' } }} key={idx}>
      <li className={'DeptList'}>
        {obj.CRS_SUBJ_CD} - {obj.DEPT_NAME}
      </li>
    </Link>
  )
})
```

This is the Link to that I am trying to use, and I am sending in `linkState` that has a string of hello. To receive it I have tried `this.props.location.state` and `this.props.history.location.state` but they both result in error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.history.location').

Not sure what can be causing this. Any insight would be great.

**EDIT:** the `CoursePage` component below:

```
render () {
    console.log(this.props.location.linkState)
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <header className="Header"></header>
        <div>
          <h1>Dept</h1>
          <p><ListCourse letter={this.props.title}/></p>
        </div>
        <footer className="Footer">This is the footer</footer>
      </div>
    )
  };
```

Comment: Could you post what the `coursePage` component looks like?

Comment: the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30115324/12348877

Comment: try console.log(this.props.location.state.linkState), it should work fine if you're on class component.

Comment: If he is on a functional component he does not have access to `this.props`

Comment: I posted the coursePage component above. And @CanUver I have seen that link and I couldn't find it helpful. Maybe I might have missed something. Will take a look at it once more.

Comment: @ShalinPatel , are you using functional component or a class component. It simply may be refering to the missing `this.props`

Comment: I posted both cases in an answer below, I think he knows better what kind of component he uses.

Comment: @dabishan I am using a functional component and I have included the this.props

Comment: @ShalinPatel, you are contradicting yourself in this reply and @CevaComic's answer. But if you are using functional component, you cannot use `this.props` and have to follow this structure `export default CoursePage = (props) => console.log(props.location.state)` as done in the first block of @CevaComic's answer

Comment: I am so sorry. I meant to say I am using class component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter) HOC to make `history` and other [route-props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/route-props) available in your class component:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
class CoursePage extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.debug(this.props) // it will print all route-props (history, location, match)
  }
  render() {
    return <>CoursePage</>
  }
}

export default withRouter(CoursePage)
```

If using functional component, you can use [useHistory](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook:

```
const history = useHistory(); // inside function component
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using functional components , the state is stored in props.location.state

```js
export default props => {
    console.log('state', props.location.state)

    return null
}
```

If you are using class components you must use the constructor in order to get the props. And your state will be stored in this.props.location.state

```js
export default class Demo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        console.log('state', this.props.location.state)

        return null
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have a class component and I have the constructor with the props

Comment: Use of [constructor](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) is not must if it is doing nothing except `super(props)`. Yes, it is must when you are initializing the state i.e.`this.state = { ... code }` or binding methods :)