# How can I pass props to another components with in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass product data from AllProducts component to Product component.

`AllProducts.jsx`: is showing all the products I have and `Product.jsx` will show specific product and how can I pass data to `Product.jsx`?

Here is my `AllProducts.jsx`:

```
const AllProducts = (props) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const getProductsAPI = () => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8000/api/products")
      .then((res) => {
        setProducts(res.data);
        getProductsAPI();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getProductsAPI();
  }, [props]);

  return (
    <div>
      <table className="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {products.map((product, i) => (
            <tr key={i}>
              <th scope="row">{i}</th>
              <td>{product.title}</td>
              <td>
                <Link to={`/products/${product._id}`}> View </Link>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
```

and here is my `Product.jsx`:

```
const Product = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h4>{props.product.title}</h4>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Here is my project github if you want to look at all the code I have: https://github.com/nathannewyen/full-mern/tree/master/product-manager

Answer (score 1):

- If the data is fully loaded for each product in AllProducts, and you don't want to make another API call by product id in the Product component, in this case, you don't have to use a route link to view Product, just make a conditional rendering to show Product component inside AllProducts component. pseudo-code as below,

  ```
      const [showProduct, setShowProduct] = useState(false);
      const [currentProduct, setCurrentProduct] = useState();
      const showProduct = (product) => {
        setShowProduct(true);   
        setCurrentProduct(product);         
       }     
       <tbody>
          {products.map((product, i) => (
            <tr key={i}>
              <th scope="row">{i}</th>
              <td>{product.title}</td>
              <td>
                <button type="button" onclick = {showProduct(product)}>View</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>

      return (showProduct ? <Product /> : <AllProucts/>)
  ```
- If you also need to make another API call to get extra data for each product, then use the router link but perhaps you can not pass props.

Comment: So If I dont want to make the API call but can I create another file just for each product?

Comment: If you stick to the router link, refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115324/pass-props-in-link-react-router).