# How to send data to another page in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, react-router

Here I have a problem in ReactJS, in the POST fetch section in NewCases.jsx. There will generate Data i.e. app_uid, then I want to send app_uid data from NewCases.jsx to DNNewCases.jsx, but I don't know how.
This is the Full Script:

**NewCases.jsx**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import './NewCases.css'
import user2 from '../../images/user2.png';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import DNNewCases from '../DynaformCases/DNNewCases';


class NewCases extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            token: sessionStorage.getItem("access_token"),
            username: sessionStorage.getItem("username"),
            user_role: '',
            allcases: [],
            inMemoryCases: [],
            showProcess: [],
            dataSess: [],
            app_uid: '',
            dataselanjutnya: '',
            search: '',
        }
        this.getDetailCase = this.getDetailCase.bind(this);
        this.searchData = this.searchData.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("access_token") === null) {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        }

        fetch('https://bpm.*************.or.id/api/1.0/************/extrarest/session-id', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
            },
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson);
                this.setState({
                    dataSess: responseJson,
                });
            });


        fetch("https://bpm.***********.or.id/api/1.0/***********/extrarest/login-user", {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
            }
        }).then(result => result.json()).then(resultJSON => {
            this.getUserRole(resultJSON.uid);
        })
        fetch('https://bpm.**************.or.id/api/1.0/************/case/start-cases', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
            },
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson[0]);
                this.setState({
                    allcases: responseJson,
                    inMemoryCases: responseJson,
                });
            });
    }

    getUserRole = (uid) => {
        fetch("https://bpm.***********.or.id/api/1.0/************/user/" + uid, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
            }
        }).then(result => result.json()).then(resultJSON => {
            if (resultJSON.usr_role == "PROCESSMAKER_ADMIN") {
                this.setState({ user_role: 'Administrator' })
            } else if (resultJSON.usr_role == "PROCESSMAKER_OPERATOR") {
                this.setState({ user_role: 'Operator' })
            } else if (resultJSON.usr_role == "PROCESSMAKER_MANAGER") {
                this.setState({ user_role: 'Manager' })
            }
        })
    }

    getDetailCase(pro, tas) {
        fetch("https://bpm.***************.or.id/api/1.0/************/cases/", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'pro_uid': pro,
                'tas_uid': tas,
            }),
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    showProcess: responseJson,
                });
                this.state.app_uid = (this.state.showProcess.app_uid);
            });
    }


    searchData = (event) => {
        this.setState({ search: event.target.value })
        const searchData = this.state.inMemoryCases.filter(
            data => {
                let lowerCase = (data.pro_title).toLowerCase()
                let searchLowerCase = this.state.search.toLowerCase()

                return lowerCase.indexOf(searchLowerCase) > -1;
            }
        );
        this.setState({ allcases: searchData });
    }


    render() {
        return (

            <Fragment>
                <div className="background-nya">
                    <div className="header">
                        <Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} to="/menu">
                            <p className="headerLabel-fix"> ********** </p>
                        </Link>
                        <p className="headerLabelUser"> {this.state.username} </p>
                        <p className="headerLabelPass"> {this.state.user_role} </p>
                        <img className="userIcon" src={user2} />
                    </div>
                    <p className="titlePage"> PROCESS LIST </p>
                    <div className="form-search">
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.searchData} placeholder="search"></input>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    {
                        this.state.allcases.map((process) => {
                            { this.getDetailCase(process.pro_uid, process.tas_uid) }
                            return (
                                <Fragment>
                                    <Link
                                        to={{
                                            pathname: "/dynaform",
                                            state: this.state.app_uid
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        <div key={process.pro_uid} className="caseList" onClick={this.alertShow}>
                                            {process.pro_title}
                                        </div>
                                    </Link>
                                </Fragment>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>

            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default NewCases;
```

**DNNewCases.jsx**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import user2 from '../../images/user2.png';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Iframe from 'react-iframe'


class DNNewCases extends Component {

    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            username: sessionStorage.getItem("username"),
            token: sessionStorage.getItem("access_token"),
            dataSess: [],

        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("access_token") === null) {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        }

        fetch('https://bpm.**********.or.id/api/1.0/**********/extrarest/session-id', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
            },
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson);
                this.setState({
                    dataSess: responseJson,
                });
            });
    }
    
    render() {

        return (
        <Iframe url= {'https://bpm.************.or.id/***********/en/neoclassic/cases/open?APP_UID=&DEL_INDEX=1&action=EDIT&sid=' + this.state.dataSess}
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            display="block"
            position="fixed" />
        )
    }
    
}

export default DNNewCases;
```

Hopefully I can find a solution here. Thank you very much

Comment: `this.state.app_uid = (this.state.showProcess.app_uid);` - you are directly mutating your state. i suggest to set this new app_uid in `setState`

Answer (score 0):

you can use props when navigating between components,

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115324/pass-props-in-link-react-router), to pass data between router link

if not for a better solution, try using [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started).

youtube tutorial click [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxIDLw0M-m0)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using "react-redux".

With [mapDispatchToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch) and some actions, you could save the new data in a reducer, then you could access the data with [mapStateToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate).

Links above provide some examples and I personally recommend youtube tutorials from [techsith](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Erbf5NXQQw).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the usage of [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter)

```
export default withRouter(props => <NewCases {...props} />);
```

From ReactTraining Docs:

> You can get access to the history object’s properties and the closest
> 's match via the withRouter higher-order component. withRouter
> will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped
> component whenever it renders.

Once you get access to your `history`, make use of this snippet to reroute:

```
this.props.history.push(`/someRoute`);
```

Simply call this snippet in your `setState` callback after your API call & after you've set the correct state to `app_uid`. As I stated in my comment, it appears you are directly mutating your state. I highly suggest to set the new `app_uid` inside the `setState` function

As a side note: I do not see your `Route` configurations. This answer assumes you've at least set up your client-side-routing on your original code base.