# Pass props from react router Link in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

How can I pass props to another component using React router link?

I tried to do it like this. However, it is not working.
By this I mean props are not passing through.
I want to pass information of currencies to another component and than use It.
Any suggestions?

```
return <Div>
        <div className="header">
            <Heading>Welcome To CoinValue </Heading>
        </div>
        <Ul>
            {currentItems.map(currencies => {
                return <Link
                    key={uuidv4()}
                    to={`/cryptoValute/${currencies.id}`
                    props={currencies}}><Li>{currencies.name}</Li></Link>
            })}
            <div>
                {this.renderPagination()}
            </div>
        </Ul>
    </Div>
```

Comment: Could you please give a better description of what you look to accomplish with this code? You could simply pass the props to another component without needing to use <Link />.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass props in Link react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115324/pass-props-in-link-react-router)

Comment: @AlbertoPerez I especially need to pass props through the link

Comment: @k-wasilewski I'm trying that way but still cant make it tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao, try to modify your code like this:

```
return <Div>
    <div className="header">
        <Heading>Welcome To CoinValue </Heading>
    </div>
    <Ul>
        {currentItems.map(currencies => {
            return <Link
                key={uuidv4()}
                to={{pathname: `/cryptoValute/${currencies.id}`, query: {currencies}}}><Li>{currencies.name}</Li></Link>
                
        })}
        <div>
            {this.renderPagination()}
        </div>
    </Ul>
</Div>
```

Then in your component, to retrieve `currencies` value you could do `this.props.location.query.currencies`.

Comment: Its giving me synax error on this line `to={{pathname: `/cryptoValute/${currencies.id}`, query: {currencies}}}`>`

Comment: Oh, sorry I wrongly put one ` after query. I updated my answer. Check now.