# This react onClick does not work is this Router Link wrong?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I learn React and wanted to get `react-router-dom` working but something is wrong in the code

Basically I have a click on an image that goes here:

```
onImageClick = val => {
   return(
    <Link
    to={{
      pathname: "/timeLineViewer",
      productdetailProps: {
       productdetail: {val.week }
      }
      }}>
     </Link>
     )
  };
```

But the `Link` should call `TimeLineViewer` constructor but its not working

Here is App

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import Header from "./components/structure/Header";
import Content from "./components/structure/Content";
import Footer from "./components/structure/Footer";
import TimeLineViewer from './components/sections/TimeLineViewer'

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Content />
        <Footer />
      </div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/timeLineViewer">
          <TimeLineViewer />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Please advice I'm new to React

**UPDATE**
Here is the Component that has the `onImageClick`

```
//import Timeline from "../elements/Timeline";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Resume from "../../resume.json";
import TimeLineViewer from "./TimeLineViewer"
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export default class Timeline extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this)
        this.changeSlider = this.changeSlider.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            slideIndex: 0,
            updateCount: 0,
            settings: {
                dots: false,
                infinite: true,
                speed: 500,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                afterChange: () =>
                    this.setState(state => ({ updateCount: state.updateCount + 1 })),
                beforeChange: (current, next) => this.setState({ slideIndex: next })
            }
        }
    }

    changeHandler(e) {
        this.sliderWrapper.slider.slickGoTo(e.target.value)
    }

    changeSlider() {
        this.setState({
            slideIndex: this.sliderWrapper.slider.innerSlider.state.currentSlide
        })
    }

    changeUpdateCount(e) {
        this.setState({
            updateCount: this.state.updateCount + 1
        }, () => console.log(`test state after update: ${this.state.updateCount}`))
    }

    onImageClick = val => {
       // TimeLineViewer={val.week}
       return(
        <Link
        to={{
          pathname: "/timeLineViewer",
          productdetailProps: {
           productdetail: "I M passed From Props"
          }
       }}>
         </Link>
         )
      };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container" id="timeline">
                <h2>Slick Go To</h2>
                <p>Total updates: {this.state.settings.updateCount} </p>
                <input onChange={this.changeHandler} value={this.state.slideIndex} type='range' min={0} max={3} />
                <SliderWrapper onImageClick={this.onImageClick}
                    ref={sliderWrapper => this.sliderWrapper = sliderWrapper}
                    beforeChange={this.changeUpdateCount.bind(this)}
                    afterChange={this.changeSlider.bind(this)}
                    slideIndex={this.state.slideIndex}
                    updateCount={this.state.updateCount}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}


class SliderWrapper extends React.Component {

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        // certain condition here, perhaps comparison between this.props and nextProps
        // and if you want to update slider on setState in parent of this, return true, otherwise return false
        if (this.props.updateCount !== nextProps.updateCount) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    sliders() {
        return Resume.weeks.map(week => {
            return (
                // Timeline items
                <section className="timeline-carousel">
                    <h1>week {week.week}</h1>
                    <div className="timeline-carousel__item-wrapper" data-js="timeline-carousel">
                        <div className="timeline-carousel__item">
                            <div key={week} className="timeline-carousel__image">
                                <img onClick={() => this.props.onImageClick(week)} alt="image" src={week.frontImage}  />
                                <h2>UNDER CONSTRUCTION IN PROGRES..</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div className="timeline-carousel__item-inner">
                            <div className="pointer" />
                                <span className="year">{week.year}</span>
                                <span className="month">{week.albumDate}</span>
                                <p>{week.summary}</p>
                                <a href="#" className="read-more">Read more</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
             )
        });
    }

    render() {
        const settings = {
            dots: false,
            infinite: false,
            speed: 100,
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            afterChange: this.props.afterChange,
            beforeChange: this.props.beforeChange,
            responsive: [
                {
                  breakpoint: 700,
                  settings: {
                    arrows: false,
                    slidesToShow: 3
                  }
                },
                {
                  breakpoint: 500,
                  settings: {
                    arrows: false,
                    slidesToShow: 2
                  }
                },
                {
                  breakpoint: 400,
                  settings: {
                    arrows: false,
                    slidesToShow: 1
                  }
                }
            ]
        };
        return (
            <div >
                <Slider ref={slider => this.slider = slider} {...settings}>
                    {this.sliders()}
                </Slider>
            </div>
        );


    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Here's an image what it looks like
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case you have something like that in your codebase

```
const Container = () => {
...
return (
...
  <img src="..." onClick={onImageClick = val => {
   return(
    <Link
      to={{
        pathname: "/timeLineViewer",
        productdetailProps: {
        productdetail: {val.week }
        }
       }} />
     )
  };}/>
...
)
}
```

It's wrong because if you want to redirect onClick you need to use history API https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory
If you put Link in return of onClick event, it can't reach JSX and never renders. So if Link wasn't rendered it shouldn't work)

Also you can wrap your image with link

```
const Container = () => {
...
return (
...

   <Link
      to={{
        pathname: "/timeLineViewer",
        productdetailProps: {
        productdetail: {val.week }
        }
       }}>
      <img src="..." />
   </Link>
     )
  };}/>
...
)
}
```

***UPDATE***
Something like that should work

```
...
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class Timeline extends React.Component {

....
    onImageClick = val => {
        const {history} = this.props;
       // TimeLineViewer={val.week}
       history.push("/timeLineViewer", {productdetailProps: {
           productdetail: "I M passed From Props"
          }});
      };

    ....
    }
}

export default withRouter(Timeline)
```

Comment: Thanks I updated my question, the `onImageClick` is just a function

Comment: In your case you need to use history. You can add it to your component by HOC https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter.

Comment: Added sample for withRouter and history

Comment: Thanks looks like it working but only on first click. The TimeLineViewer Constructor is getting the props but clicking again Constructor is not running. I know of course it's only run on creating the component.

Comment: I added a picture to my question to illustrate

Comment: Can you add sandbox example? Also  yagizhan.avci comment under first answer could help you)

Comment: Thanks I created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gretas-site-carousel-tex-not-straight-75nwm?file=/src/TimeLineViewer.js) Look at the image above in my post to see how it works

Comment: When you click on different images url never changes, You need to add query params to your link to make it work. @yagizhan.avci added link to a solution for your question) take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115324/pass-props-in-link-react-router

Comment: ok It works now I'm new to React. When using your code the render method in TimeLineViewer does fire.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change this

```js
        <Route path="/timeLineViewer">
          <TimeLineViewer />
        </Route>
```

To this

```js
        <Route path="/timeLineViewer" component={TimeLineViewer} />
```

Comment: Thanks I think I do something wrong because the TimeLineViewer Component is already loaded and  visible in the doom so constructor has already been fired. How to pass this props to it?

Comment: I think this link solves your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115324/pass-props-in-link-react-router