# Problem Passing props using Link and NavLink in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom, react-props

i have 2 main components

- SurveyList, used to display all survey data
- Survey, used to update survey data

when i click edit button in survey list, it shows selected survey id on url, but not able to pass to Survey Component

Like this

[image]

this is my Route for SurveyComponent

```
 <Route path="/survey/:id" component={Survey} />
```

And here is Link to

```
 <Link to={`/survey/${currentsurvey.id}`/>
```

I also tried different methods fot this, but none of them are working.

Comment: update your route component as well

Comment: Please take a look at this Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115324/pass-props-in-link-react-router

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the docs how to access the `:id` inside the route component [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params)

```
import {
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";
...
...

  const { id } = useParams();
...
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Add Exact to the Route

```js
<Route exact path="/survey/:id" component={Survey} />
```