# How to pass props from one page using a Link(react-router) to a class component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-context, react-component

I have a Link in a page and I want it to pass the props to a route component which is a class component, how can I do that?? here is the code I have done so far:

the file where the Link is :

```
<List
    itemLayout="horizontal"
    dataSource={classes}
    renderItem={item => (
        <List.Item>
            <List.Item.Meta
                title = {
                    <Link 
                        to={{
                           pathname : "/Class",
                           state: {Name: item.Name}
                        }}
                        className="ListItem"
                    >
                        {item.Name}
                    </Link>
                 }
             />
         </List.Item>
       )}
/>
```

this is the index.js where I stored all the routes and I also have a context. Provider:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store= {store}>
      <Router>
        <Layout>
          <Switch>
              <Route component={LandingPage} exact path="/" />
              <Route path="/dashboard" >
                <UserProvider>
                  <Dashboard/>
                </UserProvider>
              </Route>
              <Route path="/Class" >
                <UserProvider>
                  <Class/>
                </UserProvider>
              </Route>
              <Route component={NewMessage} path="/New-Message" />
              <Route path="/Inbox" >
                <UserProvider>
                  <Inbox/>
                </UserProvider>
              </Route>
              <Route path="/Outbox" >
                <UserProvider>
                  <Outbox/>
                </UserProvider>
              </Route>
              <Route component={ResetPassword} path="/reset-password" />
              <Route component={ResetPasswordConfirmed} path="/reset/password/confirm/:uid/:token" />
              <Route component={Signup} path="/signup" />
              <Route component={Activate} path="/activate/:uid/:token" />
            
          </Switch>
        </Layout>
      </Router>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and this is the file that the link is pointing at (Class.js) :

```
class Class extends React.Component {
    
    static contextType = userContext
    
    state = {
        Curriculum: [],
        Classworks: [], 
        Homeworks: [],
        activeClass: ""
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        
        const { state } = props.location.state

        this.setState({
            activeClass: state
        });
        console.log(this.state.activeClass);        
      }

    render()
        {
            const { user_data, classes } = this.context
            return(
            <div className="back">
            <Navbar/>
            {this.state.activeClass}
            <main className= "MainContent">
                <div className="Class">
                    <h2 className="class">
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </main>
            <br/>
            <footer className="Footer">Designed by Eng. Omar Redwan</footer>
        </div>
        )}
}

export default Class;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass props in Link react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115324/pass-props-in-link-react-router)

Comment: By pass props do you mean pass route state to a component? What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The `Class` component isn't directly rendered by a `Route` component so it doesn't receive the [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props).

```
<Route path="/Class" >
  <UserProvider>
    <Class/>
  </UserProvider>
</Route>
```

## Solution

Wrap the export of the `Class` component with the [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component so it has the route props injected to it.

```
export default withRouter(Class);
```

Now the `Class` component should be able to access route state via the `location` prop.

```
const { location: { state } } = this.props;
```

## Side Note

You can't log react state *right* after an enqueued update as react state updates are asynchronously processed *between* render cycles, so you'll only ever see the current state from the current render cycle.

```
this.setState({
  activeClass: state
});
console.log(this.state.activeClass); // <-- current state!
```

Use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method to log state/prop updates.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Link 
  to={{
   pathname: "/Class",
   state: item.Name
  }}
   className="ListItem">
   {item.Name}
</Link>
```

and access like this in navigated component

```
componentDidMount() {
        const { state } = this.props.location;

        this.setState({
            activeClass: state
        }, ()=> {
         this.state.activeClass
       });
      }
```

> Don't console state value immediately after setting to the state because it's asynchronous. If you want that console to check do as a callback to **`setState({...}, ()=> { console.log('check here') })`**

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very helpful