# React : show specific product data when user clicks on one product in the market place

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-router

i have fetched the data from an api and successfully displayed the data in a marketplace. Now when a user clicks on one product it should open the product details page and send the data of that product to populate the details page. i want to pass the specific data of one product from the Api to the product details page when that product is clicked. Please help

this is the code to render the various products

```
const renderitems = currentitems.map((item) => {
        return <div key={item.id} className="col-md-6">
            <div className="listing">
                <div className="listing-thumbnail">
                    <Link to="/listing-details-v1"><img src={ item.images[0]} alt="listing" /></Link>
```

how do i pass the id of the clicked on link to the details page

```
                      `
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass props in Link react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115324/pass-props-in-link-react-router)

Answer (score 2):

it's so simple. you'll pass product id as a parameter in the route and will get product id on the product detail page.

Step 1: Register route like

```
<Route path="/listing-details-v1/:id" ..... />
```

Step 2: Link like

```
<Link to={"/listing-details-v1/" + item.id}><img src={ item.images[0]} alt="listing" /></Link>
```

Step 3: get parameter on product detail page component like

```
        import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
        let { id } = useParams();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create Route with dynamic params
`<Route path="listing-details-v1/:id" ... />`
Then pass params with link
`` <Link to={`/listing-details-v1/${item.id}`}></Link> ``
And then you can catch it with useParams hook in your details page
`const {id} = useParams()`

Comment: when i click on the thumbnail after doing whats above, the page just becomes empty. I added <Route path="listing-details-v1/:id" /> to my App.js, did this : <Link to={"/listing-details-v1/" + item.id}><img src={ item.images[0]} alt="listing" /></Link> and this on the details page

Comment: You should add a component to your Route.

Comment: ok its opening the product details page now, so how do i use the the state in the listing details page after doing this:

Answer (score 0):

In the "listing-details-v1" page, you can declare an useState. Then using useEffect, you can map the "currentitems" to get the "item" id and inside "if" condition, if item.id matches the "id" destructured from useParams, setState the "item".

```
const details, setDetails = useState([]);
const {id} = useParams(); //import from react-router-dom


useEffect(() => {
    const getDetails = currentitems.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        return setDetails(item);
      }
    });
  }, [id]);

 return (
     <>
        <h1>{details.title}<h1/>
     </>
    )
```