# How can I pass data from one page to another React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am new in react, and I am working on a project. I have two pages/components. I take details of user on page and want to show data on another page. But I am not able to do it.
Can somebody please help.

This is my first page `Personal.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, Row, Col, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
// import bootstrap from "bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


class Personal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h2 className="text-center my-4">Personal Information</h2>

        <div expand="md" className="container my-4 ">
          <Form >
            <Row className="my-4">
              <Col>
                <Form.Label>First Name</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control id="first_name" placeholder="First name" />
              </Col>
              
            </Row>

           
            <Link to="/Final">
              <Button
                onClick={() =>
                  this.setState({
                    name: document.getElementById("first_name").value,})}
                variant="outline-primary">{" "}Next</Button>{" "}
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Personal;
```

And this is my Second Page `Final.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Final = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Your Name{this.props.name}</h2>   
     
    </>
  );
};

export default Final;
```

Comment: This is work for me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115324/pass-props-in-link-react-router

Comment: you can use state in parent component where these two pages are called, may be `App.js`, or use some global state management, `Context API` is an easy solution with no extra dependencies for this task

Answer (score 0):

this may not solve the problem, but your `Final` component is a functional component, which accepts `props` as an argument, so instead of `this.props.name` you would just access `props.name`.
I also can't work out what's going on with the `{" "}` quotes where you're rendering your Button component?

In `Personal` you're setting the name value on *that component's* state, so you would either need to render `Final` within `Personal` so you could pass that value down, or give them a common source to read that data from, e.g. a `Context` or a common parent (like the `<App>` component).