# ReactJS : How to read value passed in Link react-router in another functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have followed the suggestion on [Pass props in Link react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115324/pass-props-in-link-react-router)

I'm sending `Link` value to the ReactJS **functional component** and while accessing it returning empty, I'm sure missing something basic here.

This is my Route path

```
            <Route path="/report/:id">
                <ReportPage />
            </Route>
```

The **report page** which is trying to get value from either query param or state param both returns empty

```
const ReportPage = (props) => {
    const { query } = useParams();
    const { hello } = useState()

    console.log(query) // Return Empty for Try #2 
    console.log(hello) // Return Empty for Try #1
    console.log(this.props.match.params.hello) // Undefined for 

    return (
        <DashboardLayout>
            <h2> AMI Test Reports </h2>
        </DashboardLayout>
    )
}
```

DashbaordPage which is Linking

**Tried 1**  Using the state

```
                   <Link
                    to={{
                        pathname: "/report/1",
                        state: {
                            hello: "Hello World"
                        }
                    }}>
                    Press Me
                </Link>
```

**Tried #2**  using the query

```
                   <Link
                    to={{
                        pathname: "/report/1",
                        query: "test"
                    }}>
                    Press Me
                </Link>
```

What is the right way to access the Value passed in the Link in another functional component.

Comment: I think this might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/react-how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

useParams returns an object containing all of the available parameters. What you currently have is useParams returning an object that contains a `params` property which is incorrect.

what you want:

```
const { id } = useParams();
```

As for the location state, you'd get that from useLocation, not useState.

```
const { state } = useLocation()
```