# How to get data of input fields from previous page when next page is loaded?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router

when "Search" is clicked, next page is loaded by the below code.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function name(){
return(
 <div className="search">
    <input type="text"placeholder="city name"></input>
    <input type="text"placeholder="number of people"></input>
    <p><Link to="/nextpage">Search</Link</p>
</div>
)
}
```

I want to take data of these input fields to fetch api using that data to make cards on next page.
How to do it?

Comment: you can use the "history" to pull the query string parameters of the url

Comment: You can pass it through params.
Here is a good answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30115524/3508399

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the general idea of how you could accomplish this. You need to store the form input (in your case, the city and number of people) in application state. You can do that using the [useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). Now this state can be managed by your first component (the one which renders the input fields) and accessed by the second component (the one that will display the values).

Because the values need to be accessed by both components, you should store the state in the parent component (see [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)). In my example, I used `App` which handles routing and renders `FirstPage` and `SecondPage`. The state values and methods to change it are passed as props.

---

Here's how you initialise the state in the `App` component:

```
const [city, setCity] = useState(null);
const [peopleCount, setPeopleCount] = useState(null);
```

`city` is the value, `setCity` is a function which enables you to modify the state. We will call `setCity` when the user makes a change in the input, like this:

```
export const FirstPage = ({ city, setCity, peopleCount, setPeopleCount }) => {

...

const handleCityChange = (e) => {
  setCity(e.target.value);
};

...

 <input
  type="text"
  placeholder="city name"
  value={city}
  onChange={handleCityChange}
/>
```

When a change in the input is made, the app will call the `setCity` function which will update the state in the parent component. The parent component can then update the `SecondPage` component with the value. We can do it simply by passing the value as a prop:

```
<NextPage city={city} peopleCount={peopleCount} />
```

Now you can do whatever you want with the value in your `SecondPage` component. Here's the full code for it, where it just displays both values:

```
export const NextPage = ({ city, peopleCount }) => {
return (
  <div>
    <p>city: {city}</p>
    <p># of people: {peopleCount}</p>
  </div>
);
};
```

---

And here's the full working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uccegh?file=src/App.js

Note that we don't have any field validation, and we have to manually write the change handlers for each input. In a real app you should avoid doing all this by yourself and instead use a library to help you build forms, such as [Formik](https://formik.org/docs/overview).