# Passing a function works, but doesn't change the variable

Tags: reactjs

I'm passing a function to another component in the link. In another component, I make a query to api, when the query is executed I go back to the previous page and execute the "openFromLogin" function. The function executes because it returns console.log, but the variable is still false.

I want to do so that after logging in and redirecting it automatically opens the modal.

Please help, thanks :)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

function ProductSidebarOne(props) {
  const [openPricing, setOpenPricing] = useState(false);
  
  const openFromLogin = () => {
    setOpenPricing(true);
    console.log("done");
  }
  console.log(openPricing);

  return (
    <>
      <Link to={{ pathname: `/login`, state: { from: props.location.pathname }, openFromLogin }} className="font-orange font-semibold">Log in</Link>
      <Modal
        isOpen={openPricing}
        shouldFocusAfterRender={false}
        className="pricing-popup"
        closeTimeoutMS={10}
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-body">
              <button type="button" className="close" aria-label="Close" style={{ position: 'absolute', right: '0', top: '0' }}>
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>

            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-link btn-sm">Close</button>
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Send</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </>
  )
}

export default ProductSidebarOne;
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import { setUserSession } from '../../../../utils';

function Login(props) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const openFromLogin = props.location.openFromLogin;

  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios.post("api url", {
      email: email,
      password: password
    })
    .then(response => {
      setUserSession(response.data);
      props.history.push(props.location.state.from, openFromLogin());
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="login-page">
      <form onSubmit={handleLogin} className="mb-0">
        <input type="text" className="form-control" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
        <input type="password" className="form-control" value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
        <div className="form-footer">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicated in [Pass props in Link react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115324/pass-props-in-link-react-router)

AFAIK you cannot do that with `Link`. You would have to pass either path or query parameters, since `Link` is basically just an anchor to an url.

What you could do instead is setting up a "global" state with [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) which gets manipulated after successfully logging in. Your `ProductSidebarOne` could then subscribe, "use", that context and react to it, if it fulfills the requirements.

Example: Setup a `AuthenticationContext` and set `loggedIn` to `true` after successfully logging in. `useContext` for `AuthenticationContext` in `ProductSidebarone` and `useEffect` on `loggedIn` from the context to `setOpenPricing(true)`.

I hope this clarifies it.

EDIT:

I will try to provide a minimal example, including the missing provider. Note that this is not tested.

```js
import React, { createContext } from 'react';

// Create and export context
export const AuthenticationContext = createContext({
  loggedIn: false,
  setLoggedIn: () => {},
});
```

```js
//e.g. App.js
import { AuthenticationContext } from 'PATH';

const App = () => {
   ...
   // Hold state for context
   const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

   return (
      ...
      // Provide context to child components in app
      <AuthenticationContext.Provider value={{loggedIn, setLoggedIn}}>
         ...
      </AuthenticationContext.Provider>
   )
}
```

```js
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

import { AuthenticationContext } from '../../../others/common/context';

function ProductSidebarOne(props) {
  const [openPricing, setOpenPricing] = useState(false);

  // Connect to context
  const { loggedIn } = useContext(AuthenticationContext);

  // Here we can use the state inside context
  // e.g. react to change in context
  useEffect(() => {
     if(loggedIn) setOpenPricing(true)
  }, [loggedIn])

  return (...)
}
```

```js
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import { setUserSession } from '../../../../utils';
import { AuthenticationContext } from '../common/context';

function Login(props) {
  ...

  const { loggedIn, setLoggedIn } = useContext(AuthenticationContext);

  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios.post("api url", {
      email: email,
      password: password
    })
    .then(response => {
      setUserSession(response.data);
      // Manipulate state from any child
      setLoggedIn(true);
      props.history.push(props.location.state.from);
    });
  }

  return (...)
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: I have tried this solution and it doesn't work or i am doing something wrong. The problem is probably that the components are not connected by the provider and I have no way of getting them connected.

I will put the code below.

Comment: Yes, you have to wrap components that will use the context (probably your whole application?) with a provider. This provider ultimately holds the state for authentication which will trigger rerendering on all connected components.

Comment: I edited the answer with an example including a provider. Please see if that helps.